# Round 2nd decimal place when performing calculation within awk

Tags: ksh, aix

here is a simple example:

```
echo "36974820" | awk '{print "("$1 " KB)" " (" $1/1024 " MB)" " (" $1/1024/1024 " GB)\n"}'
```

Output:

```
(36974820 KB) (36108.2 MB) (35.2619 GB)
```

What I want is below:

```
(36974820 KB) (36108.2 MB) (35.26 GB)
```

I know it is possible to use the below separately:

```
echo "5.5434" | awk '{printf "%.2f\n", $1}'
```

Output is:

```
5.54
```

I want to combined the above with my awk to perform the calculations to round to 2nd decimal place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `printf` directly instead of `print` in `awk` (at least GNU awk):

```
user@host $ echo "36974820" | awk '{printf("(%d kB)  (%.2f MB)  (%.2f GB)\n", $1, $1/1024, $1/1024/1024)}'
(36974820 kB)  (36108.22 MB)  (35.26 GB)
```

Comment: Perfect. Works for me :)

Comment: You're welcome. If you find the answer helpful, you may want to consider accepting it so that others with similar questions may find it more easily.